# Backup/Archive a particular version of an app

Tags: itunes, backup, ios-appstore, ios

How can I archive a my currently installed app version (particular version) of an iOS app (=export IPA file?)

I am aware that apple removed the App Store from iTunes and that apps are not part of the backups any more.

However I am looking for a solution with which I can draw my currently installed app version as IPA file before I upgrade.

Since app authors can modify and remove functionality at will and Apple prevents people from going back to a previous version I would like to be safe, particularly when large changes happen.

I have looked into iMazing but it only seems to be able to export the latest version from the AppStore to IPA (neither the currently installed version nor different version)

Comment: Have you tried this? https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208079

Comment: In addition to @SteveChambers comment: According to some news I have read those old iTunes version do no longer work on moderns MacOS versions. The only old iTunes versions that as far as I know still work without problems for downloading IPAs are the PC/Windows versions.

Answer (score 0):

This isn’t feasible since you can’t really restore or install the IPA even should you manage to back them up. We engage with app developers as a business so they can sell to us direct when we need to manage upgrade cadence or pin an app, but ever forward is the model for consumers now.